# PostgreSQL Size doubled

Tags: postgresql

I have a production database that was 7gb large.  24 hours later it jumped to 10gb and 24 hours after that it was 14 gigabytes.  I've tried pg_dumping it and restoring it.  I've tried vacuuming it.  I've tried re-indexing it.  What else could have caused this jump in size?  I'm currently using PostgreSQL 9.1.

Any suggestions on where to go from here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you measuring the size? Any chance it's WAL building up in `pg_xlog` due to a stalled replica?

Comment: Is it actually a problem that you're using more disk space?  Or are you concerned that something is wrong?

Comment: I'm measuring size by doing the pg_dump and looking at how big it is.  I know there are ways to determine size on disk with queries but I've found those to usually be consistent with the size when downloaded.

Comment: I'm concerned something is wrong.  I don't know why it could jump in size so much so quickly.

Comment: The size of the dump will *not* reflect the size of your database on disk. The dump file only contains the *definition* of the indexes. So you are not counting the size of the indexes on disk. Additionally binary data stored in `bytea` columns will be exported as hex encoded using much more space in the dump file than on disk. A more reliable way is to use `pg_database_size()`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBOBJECT

Comment: select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('db')); Gives me 16 GB and the dump gives me 14 gigabytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using < v9.1 this query from [the postgres wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage) will query all relations and their sizes.  this will work with any version of PGSQL.

If you are using v9.1+ you can do

```
\d+
```

That will show you the size of all relations.

For just tables:
    \dt+

For sequences:

```
\ds+
```

and so on

You may also want to check and see if your autovacuum is happening:

```
select * from pg_stat_all_tables;
```

You can also run a vacuum manually:

```
vacuum full verbose
```

A normal vacuum does not remove dead rows a vacuum full does.  Running it with verbose will output a lot of useful information about how many dead rows, etc.

Comment: I figured out the problem using some of the stats.  Thank you

Comment: Glad to help - we just recently went through this with a bloated DB.  Also - Thanks for my first accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the on-disk size is increasing, there are lots of reasons that could happen.

But since the size of pg_dump files is getting bigger, it is almost certainly because someone is inserting data into your database, or updating existing rows with larger values.

Perhaps you can set `log_statement = 'mod'` to figure it out.

Or you can use command line tools like `diff` between the successive pg_dump files.  You might have to use `head` or `tail` to limit the amount of data fed to `diff`.